# Why do I need a temporary variable to store the value of a Random method?

Tags: java, random

So I'm trying to run a simple 'generate random numbers' programme, and I can't understand why I need a temporary variable to store the value of the number generate. And also why do I print `"" + variable` instead of `variable`.

Example:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class compountInterest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Random dice = new Random();
        num = dice.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println("" + num);

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need one. Especially if it's not declared.

Comment: can you show me how I can write it?

Comment: `System.out.println("" + dice.nextInt(6));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall direct print it.

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class compountInterest {

        public static void main(String[] args){

            System.out.println("" + new Random().nextInt(6));

            System.out.println(new Random().nextInt(6));

//Appending empty char at start makes no difference

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Can you explain to me why we put println("" + new Random..) ? why not just println(new randome...);

Comment: You do not need a "" to be appened to the random value, I added just because you added in your question.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm learning from "thenewboston" on youtube, thats how he did it. So I wanted to know why

Comment: I have edited answer for you, to better explain. Please note SO is not a tutorial site for these question. I suggest you read good books for learning.

Comment: Can you suggest something to start with?

Comment: Head first Java is a simple book to get hold of basics.